# Get original password from a hashed password from database in an input in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, password-hash

I have a users page where there is add and edit users information and I'm trying to get the original password from hashed password from database in an input in PHP and MYSQL. I've tried this code:

```
if(isset($_GET['add']) || isset($_GET['edit'])){
    $name = ((isset($_POST['name']))?sanitize($_POST['name']):'');
    $email = ((isset($_POST['email']))?sanitize($_POST['email']):'');
    $password = ((isset($_POST['password']))?sanitize($_POST['password']):'');
    $confirm = ((isset($_POST['confirm']))?sanitize($_POST['confirm']):'');
    $permissions = ((isset($_POST['permissions']))?sanitize($_POST['permissions']):'');
    $errors = array();
    if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
      $edit_id = (int)$_GET['edit'];
      $userResults = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$edit_id'");
      $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userResults);
      $name = ((isset($_POST['name']))?$_POST['name']:$user['full_name']);
      $email = ((isset($_POST['email']))?$_POST['email']:$user['email']);
      $password = ((isset($_POST['password']))?$_POST['password']:$user['password']);
      $confirm = ((isset($_POST['confirm']))?sanitize($_POST['confirm']):'');
      $permissions = ((isset($_POST['permissions']))?$_POST['permissions']:$user['permissions']);
    }

    if($_POST){
      $emailQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
      $emailCount = mysqli_num_rows($emailQuery);


      if($emailCount != 0 && $_GET['add']){
        $errors[] = 'That email already exists in our database.';
      }

      $required = array('name', 'email', 'password', 'confirm', 'permissions');
      foreach($required as $f){
        if(empty($_POST[$f])){
          $errors[] = 'You must fill out all fields.';
          break;
        }
      }
      if(strlen($password) < 6){
        $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters.';
      }

      if($password != $confirm){
        $errors[] = 'Your passwords do not match.';
      }

      if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $errors[] = 'You must enter a valid email.';
      }

      if(!empty($errors)){
        echo display_errors($errors);
      }else{
        //add user to database
        $hashed = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $mql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name,email,password,permissions) VALUES ('$name','$email','$hashed','$permissions')";
        $_SESSION['success_flash'] = $name.' has been added.';
        if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
          $mql = "UPDATE users SET `full_name` = '$name', `email` = '$email',
          `password` = '$hashed', `permissions` = '$permissions'
          WHERE id = '$edit_id'";
        }
        $db->query($mql);
        header('Location: users.php');
      }
    }
<h3 class="text-center"><?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'Edit':'Add A New');?> User</h3><hr>
    <form action="users.php?<?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'edit='.$edit_id:'add=1');?>" method="post">
<div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" value="<?php if(password_verify($password, $user['password'])){echo $password;}?>">
      </div>
}else{
// Add user HTML
```

But the input is empty... I can't seem to find the error in the code. If I remove `password verify` code in HTML and replace it with `<?=$password;?>` I'm getting the hashed password not the original. All fields are working except confirm and password.

Comment: https://www.md5online.org/md5-decrypt.html

Comment: You should never decrypt a password. That would mean you pass it in plain text through internet to the user, which can be intercepted. Let the user create a new password instead

Comment: @SSpoke password_hash is not MD5.

Comment: @Andreas, this is the admin dashboard where admin can edit and see the passwords of the employees. Now, if the admin press edit. The password will be hashed and entered as a hash!!!

Comment: I don't care what it is, nobody but the user/employee should know or see the password. Anything else is a invasion of the person's privacy and a security risk. In my opinion!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Hash is one way function. That's the purpose of it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: This is the admin dashboard where admin can edit and see the passwords of the employees. Now, if the admin press edit. The password will be hashed and entered as a hash!!!

Comment: @Algo, it does not matter what you want it for. It's literally impossible to do. Note that the size of the hash output has constant size. If the hash were reversible you could store a Blu-ray image in just 40 bytes or so. And obviously nobody should have access to anyone else's passwords. What do you think the chances are that no one re-used their Gmail password?

Answer (score -1):

Hashes are specifically designed to be only one-way. That's the whole reason why it's secure. Let's say a hacker got a hold of your database. If all the passwords were stored as plain text, the hacker would be able to get all of them. But, if they were all hashed, the hacker would have a hard time getting the real passwords, as there is mathematically no way to know what the original password is.

TL;DR hashes are supposed to be secure, and shouldn't be cracked. If you want to edit your user's passwords, store them as plain text.

Comment: *If you want to edit your user's passwords, store them as plain text.* **No!**

Comment: I'm trying to discourage storing passwords as plain text. Specifically, the part where I said:"If all the passwords were stored as plain text, the hacker would be able to get all of them. But, if they were all hashed, the hacker would have a hard time getting the real passwords, as there is mathematically no way to know what the original password is."

Comment: You don't need to know a password to change it administratively. It's trivial to overwrite the hash. There is *no* reason to store passwords, plaintext or otherwise. Not even one.

Comment: Ok, but when I press the edit button and left the password empty the password will be empty in the database :(